# Creating a UITableView using 2 different objects

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am stuck right now with how to create my UITableView. Right now it works fine with 1 object providing the data for it's rows and cells. The problem is, I have a 2nd object that I also want to use in the table view. Normally, this is very easy and I just create 2 sections in the UITableView and use one object for the first section, and use the second object for the second section.

But for this UITableView, I only want to use 1 section. And I need to programatically populate the row's and cell's with text from BOTH of the objects. I have no idea how to do this though when only using 1 section.

Here are all of my method implementations that help create my UITableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {


     return 1 ;

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return [self.messages count];

}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return @"Inbox Messages";


}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";

    UITableViewCell  *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    PFObject *message = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UIImage *selectMessageButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-G"];


    UIImage *selectMessageButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];



    UIButton *openMessageButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

    openMessageButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);

    [openMessageButton setImage:selectMessageButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [openMessageButton setImage:selectMessageButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [openMessageButton setImage:selectMessageButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [openMessageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    openMessageButton.tag = indexPath.row;


    [cell.textLabel setText:[message objectForKey:@"senderName"]];

    NSString *fileType = [message objectForKey:@"fileType"];

    if([fileType isEqualToString:@"image"]) {


        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_image"];


    } else {

        //no image
    }

    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:@""];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:openMessageButton];


    return cell;

}
```

The object that I am currently using with this UITableView is called `message`. I want to create a 2nd object called `message2` and place it's data in the UITableView as well.

I realize that for the `numberOfRowsInSection` method implementation I could just return the added count's of both objects, but I don't know how to work the 2nd object into the rest of the code.

Comment: I suggest you write a wrapper around your 2 data sources, which hides the complexity for the `UITableView` and also is a `UITableViewDataSource`. This wrapper must handle all changes and gives the correct object, if you ask for it.

Comment: Why not just add both arrays? `self.allMessages = [messages arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:messages2];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create one `NSArray` combining both of the `msg` arrays?  If you are populating your second msg array from somewhere, just wait until that loading is done and then do:

```
NSArray *bothArray = [msg1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:msg2];
```

You can use `bothArray` as the `datasource` for the `TableView`, when you have only one populated `msg` array, bothArray will be just the elements from `msg1`, when you have populated `msg2`, just use the code above and then call:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you have 2 arrays of 2 objects:

```
NSArray *msg1;
NSArray *msg2;
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return msg1.count + msg2.count;

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   int msg1Count = msg1.count;
   if(indexPath.row < msg1Count)
   { 
      //Here you handle object1
      PFObject *currentObject = msg1[indexPath.row];
   }
   else
    {
       //Here you handle object 2
        PFObject *currentObject = msg2[indexPath.row - msg1Count];
     }
 }
```